# How to know if an upload has started with YouTube upload widget?

Tags: javascript, upload, youtube, widget

Google launched an experimental feature called youtube upload widget. Documentation can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget).

We are able to get responses like VideoID, status after uploading videos via listeners like onUploadSuccess, onProcessingComplete, etc. Also there are ways to detect webcam actions, hence we can track those.

Is there a way to know if some upload are started ? I am looking for some Javascript function to fire an event when a user selects files from computer into the widget. (Something like onUploadStart)

Comment: I agree, this widget is great and really eases the process of uploading to Youtube from elsewhere but it really needs to show upload progress because at the moment it just doesn't look like anything is happenning.

Did you find anything we can bind to to at least display something to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there isn't this type of function. I ask this to Youtube's team on https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3011